# react-router / works well but others can't turn component that's 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router

when i use react router,only the root router's component can appear well,others errors that router will change but page can't appear,the main code:

```
    render(<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Main>
        <Route path='/' component={Menu}/>
        <Route path='/graduationRequirements' component= 
            {GraduationRequirements}/>
        <Route path='/examinationPlan' component={ExaminationPlan}/>
    </Main>
   </Router> , document.getElementById("content"));
```

when i open localhost:3000 it is ok:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwBk.png)

but when i open localhost:3000/graduationRequirements,it can't appear the GraduationRequirements component's page

Comment: since you are using hasHistory, you would write http://localhost:3000/#/graduationRequirements1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my answer help you. Byt try to put this:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Menu}/>
```

Without this React think that other paths use component={Menu}